# Exercise on Lebesgue measure ( Treatise of Analysis Vol2 by Dieudonné)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Someone challenge me to bring the solution from anywhere! So I have posted here and see, I am optimist because this website is excellent and its members are so helpful.

Let me start with this definition:

> A measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ is called diffuse if $\mu({x})=0$.
>
> Remark [Problem 7(d) & 13.9]: can be see in this part of the book

[image]

This is the exercise: P. 211

I have captured a picture scaring of misquoting the context:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Which part of the exercise gives you trouble? What is a fundamental system here? This book uses quite some obsolete terminology. I suspect there's some running hypothesis of regularity of $\mu$. Maybe it's a Borel measure?

Comment: Actually, I'm *certain* there's some running hypothesis that you failed to add: a $\{0,1\}$ measure will never satisfy the conditions you provided (as will any atomic measure with finitely many atoms). That's stronger than Borel condition. I think assuming that open sets have positive measure and that the measure is Borel should suffice, with regularity somehow following from compactness...

Comment: fundamental system means local base at $x_0$, yes this book is too old fashion. Part b and c are my problem.

Comment: Well, that's some important information you should definitely add to your question!

Comment: Thanks Tomas for pointing out this note. Could you please give a solution to even a result (under some other assumption) close to this to get the main idea or the key of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hints (assuming you have a) already, and that $X$ is metrisable and hence Polish, as the hint for c) suggests):

For b), you want to have a map $f\colon X\to [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}[[0,t)]={U_t}$, for all $t\in[0,1]$. What would $f^{-1}[\{t\}]$ be in this case? To show that $f$ is continuous, use the fact that $\bigcap_{t'>t}U_{t'}=\bigcap_{t'>t}\overline U_{t'}$ (so it's a closed set).

Notice that the continuous function in b) would be a homeomorphism if only it was injective (as both spaces are compact). We want to make a similar construction which will result in a homeomorphism at the expense of removing a null set.

To to this, we want to find a tree $T$ of open subsets of $X$ such that for any node $\sigma$ in the tree, there are finitely many sons which are disjoint open sets contained in $\sigma$ along with their closures, and which have collectively full measure in $\sigma$. Then you can recursively match each level of the tree to a finite family of disjoint open intervals in $[0,1]$, and the matching will induce the homeomorphism.